# O(N^2) shortest path algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

The problem states that we have a set of points with their coordinates and that we have to find the shortest path always beginning at (0,0) reaching a destination and going back again to (0,0) passing all inbetween points only once.

The input looks like this
on the first line are the number of inbetween points, on the second the coordinates of the destination and then the coordinates of all inbetween points. No inbetween points have the same x coordinate and the x coordinate of each inbetween point is less than that of the destination.

```
5
6 5
1 1
2 3
3 2
4 4
5 3
```

I have an implementation of the problem in the programming language C++ but the problem is I can't understand it. I've gone through it step by step but I can't understand what it does.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

const double inf = numeric_limits<double>::max(); // an infinite number

double dist [205][205] = {0};    
double res  [205][205] = {0};
int N (0);


struct point {
  double x,y;
  point(int a,int b):x(a),y(b){} 
   point(){}
}points[205];  //struct to store inbetween points

inline const bool operator < ( const point &a, const point &b ){
  return a.x < b.x;
}

int main()
{

ifstream in  ("evripos.in");
ofstream out ("evripos.out");

in>>N;
N+=2;

int t1,t2;

points[0]= point(0,0);

// stores all points 
for(int i=1;i<N;++i){
  in>>t1>>t2;
  points[i]=point(t1,t2);
}               

in.close();
sort(points,points+N); // sorts all points according to their x coordinate

// creates a 2 dimensional array of the distances between all points
// called dist
for(int i=0;i<N;++i)
  for(int j=0;j<N;++j){
    dist [i][j]= sqrt( pow(points[i].x-points[j].x,2) + pow(points[i].y-points[j].y,2));;
    res[i][j]=inf;
  }                

// computes the result, using a 2 dimensional array called res
res[0][0]=0;
for(int i=0;i<N;++i)
  for(int j=0;j<N;++j){
   res[i+1][i]   = min (res[i+1][i],   res[i][j] + dist[j][i+1]);
   res[i+1][j]   = min (res[i+1][j],   res[i][j] + dist[i][i+1]);
   res[i+1][i+1] = min (res[i+1][i+1], res[i][j] + dist[i][i+1] + dist[i+1][j]);  
  }     

out<<round(res[N-1][N-1])<<endl;       //stores the end result
out.close();
}
```

I've found out that it is a dynamic programming problem and as I understand it the whole logic is in here

```
res[0][0]=0;
for(int i=0;i<N;++i)
  for(int j=0;j<N;++j){
   res[i+1][i]  = min (res[i+1][i],   res[i][j] + dist[j][i+1]);
   res[i+1][j]  = min (res[i+1][j],   res[i][j] + dist[i][i+1]);
   res[i+1][i+1]= min (res[i+1][i+1], res[i][j] + dist[i][i+1] + dist[i+1][j]);  
  }
```

What exactly is the logic behind this? How is this problem solved with dynamic programming?

Comment: what you want in your question? You want an explanation of algorithm/implementation?

Comment: yes, why and how the algorithm works

Comment: So, you copied the code from somewhere else? This sounds like home/course work so shouldn't you be writing it yourself?

Comment: it's from a competition that happened some years ago, I took part some guy solved the problem and posted it on a forum, but I still can't figure out the O(N^2) solution

Comment: You have literally described the TSP, so I highly doubt you'll find O(N^2) solution that isn't heuristic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Bitonic tour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_tour) problem. You have a list of cities, from 0 to N-1, you need to start from city 0, go through each cities once to reach N-1 and from N-1 go back to 0.

In order to solve the problem, we need to **change the way we look at it**. Imagine there is not one, but **two people starting from city 0**, each of them will never be at same city (except 0 and N-1) and they all try to reach city N-1. So if we add the path taken by *Person one* and *Person two*, we have the answer for the original problem.

So, we have our `int [][]res`, with `res[i][j]` means the minimum total distance for *Person one* is at city `i` and *Person two* is at city `j`. We observe that this line

```
res[i+1][i]      = min (res[i+1][i],   res[i][j] + dist[j][i+1]);
```

means the *Person two* starting from city `j` will go to city `i + 1`. Notice that `i + 1` , not `i`, which will avoid the case when two persons being at same city. (Also notice that the role of `i` and `j` can be interchangeable)

Similarly

```
res[i+1][j]    = min (res[i+1][j],   res[i][j] + dist[i][i+1]);
```

means *Person one* starting from `i` go to city `i + 1`.

Finally, assume that the destination is at `i + 1`, we have

```
res[i+1][i+1]= min (res[i+1][i+1], res[i][j] + dist[i][i+1] + dist[i+1][j]);
```

***Note***: By the way we increase the index from `i` to `i + 1` in the outer `for` loop, we also guarantee that all city from 0 to i had been reached (by either *Person one* or *two*) before city `i + 1` has been reached.

So, the answer for the problem will be at `res[N-1][N-1]`

Hope that's help!

Comment: :The dynamic tsp isn't the bitonic tour, isn't it? Bitonic tour is an heuristic?http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem? The dynamic tsp algorithm is from held-karp and works similar?

Comment: @Phpdna there are several differences with the original TSP, as the distancce between each city is defined by its location in the  Cartesian coordinate system, which made the problem much simpler. However, using TSP will definitely work in this case

Comment: thanks, but why is it that in the first part of the first min it's res[i+1][i] and not res[i][i+1], but in the second min it's res[i+1][j]?

Comment: @TasostheGreat: from the position `(i, j)`, there are two choices: either the person one go from i to position i + 1 ->`(i +1, j)` or the person two go from j to position i + 1 -> `(i, i+1)`.